# How to use a record from a "echo" of a array to use into another php select

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables, select

I am trying to get a record from an "printed" array. I have this code:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            echo "<tr><td class=\"normal\" width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . 
                $row["Title"] . "</font></td>";
            echo "<td class=\"normal\" width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . 
                $row["Visor"] . "</font></td>";
            echo "<td class=\"normal\" width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . 
                convertirUrls ($row["URL"]) . "</font></td>";
            echo "<td class=\"normal\" width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . 
                $row["Name"] . "</font></td>";
            }
```

I would like to transform one record of this table in a link to generate another "query". So how can I get one record into a $variable?

Comment: .... what? You mean `$data = $row["Title"];` ?

Comment: Nop!! I mean get differents $data. For example; the result array is : title1, title2, title3, titlen.... And the array is printed int a html table. I want to reference title1(html) like a $varible1, and title2(thml) like a $variable2, ... So then each $variable will generate another select ... I don´t know if I explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?

    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="normal" width="25%"><font face="verdana"><?php echo $row["Title"] ?></font></td>
            <td class="normal" width="25%"><font face="verdana"><?php echo $row["Visor"] ?></font></td>
            <td class="normal" width="25%"><font face="verdana"><?php echo convertirUrls($row["URL"]) ?></font></td>
            <td class="normal" width="25%"><font face="verdana"><?php echo $row["Name"] ?></font></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
```

> **Note: HTML `<font>` Tag. Not Supported in HTML5.**

assign single data to variable

```
<?php

    $title =  $row["Title"] ;
    echo $title;

?>
```